# Django displaying default photo next to each category

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, django-models, django-views

Im new to Django and don't really know how to write the part of code. I have few categories under Class Offers, I would like to add default photo for each category, so while adding a new offer the default photo will be connected to the category

my Model of offer:

```
CATEGORY = (
    ("Babysitting", "Babysitting"),
    ("Housework", "Housework"),
    ("Private lessons", "Private lessons"),
    ("Agro", "Agro"),
)

class Offers(models.Model):
    category = models.CharField(choices=CATEGORY, max_length=20, null=True)

    description = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    paid_per_hr = models.IntegerField()
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True )
    updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

i'm bit stuck with problem on how to assign the default photo different to each category

```
class AddOfferView(LoginRequiredMixin, View):
    def get(self, request):
        form = OfferForm()
        return render(request, 'offer.html', {'form': form})
```

I can add the new offer with default one phono but then each category has same photo.

Comment: to be honest there a lot of way but your code example is not clear what do you mean: default photo?

Comment: I think of it when you have in ecommcerce store and web showing different categories -there is always have some default photo on web, egclothing, shoes etc.. So I am trying to add a photo of my category model of Offer. I I hope this will explain my problem